# How can i change Ionic Splash Screen Spinner Position to Bottom?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I want change my splash screen's spinner position.

```
    <preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerPosition" value="bottom" />
```

I used this code but not working.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is to remove it and make it by ur own.

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
```